# How do I customize a user registration form so it only requires email and password fields?

Tags: django

I'm following this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html) on making simple registration forms in Django. I'd like to make a user registration form that requires only two fields: "Email" and "Password." No second password field, just one.

So far, My `views.py` looks like this:

```
def register(request, template="register.html", redirect='/'):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=   RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email=          form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            raw_password=   form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            user=           authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form=   RegisterForm()
    return render(request, template, {"form": form})
```

`forms.py` has this class in it:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=      forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254)

    class Meta:
        model=  User
        fields= ("email",)
```

`register.html` looks simple:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}    
{% block main %}
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock main %}
```

In `urls.py`, I have this line in `urlpatterns`: `url("^register/$", views.register, name="register"),`.

But my registration forms looks like this, with an Email field and two Password fields: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytm5W.png. And if I fill out all three fields and hit "Register," I get this error: `UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username`.

Any idea why I'm getting this error? And how can I make sure my form only has two fields: Email and Password?

==

**UPDATE**
I changed a few things.

`models.py` now has this:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email=  models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD= "email"
```

`forms.py`"

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=      forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254)

    class Meta:
        model=  MyUser
        fields= ("email",)
```

`views.py`:

```
def register(request, template="register.html", redirect='/'):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=   RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email=  form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            raw_password=   form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            user=           authenticate(username=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form=   RegisterForm()
    return render(request, template, {"form": form})
```

The form looks the same when rendered, with one "Email" field and two password fields. But now when I try to register I get this error: `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'`. And when navigated back to the form and reentered the email I used, the page refreshed and put this message above the form: `"My user with this Email already exists."`.

So Django makes the user, but there's a problem with processing stuff after the user's creation, I guess?

Comment: Django inbuilt `User` model requires only `username` and `password`. So you can take the `email` and `password` and save it to the user model, with email being the `username`(if you want the user to login with their email id), and the reason for confirm password field is actually to confirm whether the password the user typed was not mistaken

Comment: @Bijoy So I should change `email=email` to `username=email`?

Comment: Ya because then only users can login with their `emailId` and `password`, and if you want you can also put `email=email`.